# Java, select random and insert

Tags: java

Ok, the example doesn't matter. I was just using it to put it in context. But basically i am wondering how to take a random value from an array/arraylist?

I tried using this: `int random = (int)input[Math.floor(Math.random() * input.length)];`
but it highlights potential loss of precision even though i've already `cast` it. 
Have i cast it wrong?

The example is irrelevant really and i do accept answers to all my questions.
Initially i wanted to see a correct answer without influence from me to see if i was on the right track.

Comment: The problem is fairly straight forward.  I suggest you try to write a program which loads/defines the array/list of data, and then follows the algo you suggest until you get stuck or it doesn't work and ask a more specific question.

Comment: [exact duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613373/java-batching-integers) of your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the **[bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)**. It is also [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), and thus there is no known polynomial solution ([and the general assumption is one does not exist, but it is not proven yet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)).

The problem is widely studied if you are looking for approximation algorithm, or a relatively efficient [exact algorithm](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10479-009-0557-9?LI=true)

---

**PS** - the random approach you suggest will get you a solution, but it won't be OPTIMAL.

**Counter example:**

```
arr = [2,3,4,1] , size=5
```

A possible solution to your algorithm could be: `select 3, select 1, select 4, select 2`, which will yield:

```
[3,1],[4],[2]
```

While the optimal solution will be `[3,2],[4,1]`

(-) I believe a greedy approach (chose the highest, put it in an available bin - if it fits, and if it doesn't - "open" a new bin) will do better then the randomized solution but will still be not optimal, with the counter example:

```
arr = [5,4,4,3,2,2] size = 10
```

greedy will yield `[5,4],[4,3,2],[2]` while optimal is `[5,3,2],[4,4,2]`

---

**Regarding the loss pf precision** - it happens because `Math.floor(double)` yields a `long`, while you use it as an `int` (and you might theoretically lose data when doing so). However, it is not a problem in your case since `Math.floor(Math.random() * input.length` is guaranteed to be in the range of an `int` because `input.length` is an int and `Math.random() < 1`.